# Search between dates where all dates appear

Tags: mysql, subquery, date

I want to search `house_id` where all days appear within a range of 2 dates from startDate to finalDate.

Tables columns are:

- id
- house_id
- date
- status

`house_id` + `date` are unique

the closest I could get is:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *
FROM tests) AS T1
WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-02-01' AND '2016-02-02'
HAVING COUNT(*) = DATEDIFF('2016-02-02', '2016-02-01') < 1
```

---

sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tests` ( 
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
`house_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`date` date NOT NULL,
`status` enum('0','1','2') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `tests` (`id`, `house_id`, `date`, `status`) VALUES
(1,1, '2016-02-01', '1'),
(2,1, '2016-02-02', '1'),
(3,1, '2016-02-03', '1'), 
(4,1, '2016-02-04', '1'), 
(5,1, '2016-02-05', '1'), 
(6,1, '2016-02-06', '1'), 
(7,2, '2016-02-01', '2'), 
(8,2, '2016-02-02', '2'), 
(9,2, '2016-02-04', '2'), 
(10,2, '2016-02-05', '2'), 
(11,2, '2016-02-06', '2'), 
(12,2, '2016-02-07', '2'), 
(13,2, '2016-02-08', '2')
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do or what you're asking. Could you clarify your question, pehaps with an example of what the query should return, based on your example data? Use the "edit" button in the lower-left corner of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to get `house_id` where `date` exists for each day between `@startDate` and `@finalData`.

Sample queries with 3 different `house_id`: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83aed0/4/4).

#### Query:

```
SET @startDate := CAST('2016-02-01' as date);
SET @finalDate := CAST('2016-02-04' as date);

SELECT house_id
    , COUNT(*)
    , DATEDIFF(@startDate, @finalDate)
FROM @tests AS T1
WHERE `date` > @startDate AND `date` <= @finalDate
GROUP BY house_id;
```

Query 1 in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83aed0/4/4).

This query `GROUP BY house_id` and output the `COUNT` of days between `@startDate` and `@finalData`:

```
house_id    COUNT(*)    DATEDIFF(@startDate, @finalDate)
1           3                       3
2           2                       3
3           3                       3
```

From this query, it is obvious that only rows where `COUNT(*) = DATEDIFF(@startDate, @finalDate)` should be returned.

If `(house_id, date)` is not unique, `COUNT(*)` must be replaced by `` COUNT(DISTINCT `date`) ``.

#### Query with all days

If you only want `house_id` where `COUNT(*) = DATEDIFF(day, @startDate, @finalDate)`, the query must use the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT house_id
    , COUNT(*)
FROM @tests AS T1
WHERE `date` > @startDate AND `date` <= @finalDate
GROUP BY house_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = DATEDIFF(@finalDate, @startDate)
```

Query 2 in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83aed0/4/4).

#### Output:

```
house_id    COUNT(*)
1           3
3           3
```

#### Query where `status = X`

Status value can be checked in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT house_id
    , COUNT(*)
FROM @tests AS T1
WHERE `date` > @startDate AND `date` <= @finalDate
    AND status = '1'
GROUP BY house_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = DATEDIFF(@finalDate, @startDate)
```

Query 3 in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83aed0/4/4).

#### Output:

```
house_id    COUNT(*)
1           3
```

Comment: what I need, is the oferta_id that have all days between startDate and finalDate

Comment: If I need the oferta_id that have all days between StartDate and finalDate, and all these days have to be status 1

Comment: @rafael beckert the answer now include all the option (unique date or not) and with or without status = X